# How to manually create a new empty Eloquent Collection in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

How do we create a new Eloquent Collection in Laravel 4, without using Query Builder?

There is a `newCollection()` method which can be overridden by that doesn't really do job because that is only being used when we are querying a set result.

I was thinking of building an empty Collection, then fill it with Eloquent objects. The reason I'm not using array is because I like Eloquent Collections methods such as `contains`.

If there are other alternatives, I would love to hear them out.

Answer (score 146, accepted):

It's not really Eloquent, to add an Eloquent model to your collection you have some options:

In **Laravel 5** you can benefit from a helper

```
$c = collect(new Post);
```

or

```
$c = collect();
$c->add(new Post);
```

**OLD Laravel 4 ANSWER**

```
$c = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
```

And then you can

```
$c->add(new Post);
```

Or you could use make:

```
$c = Collection::make(new Post);
```

Comment: Almost working! I think `\Illuminate\Support\Collection` is a more generic version of `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`. So I guess, it is part of Eloquent after all. Hope this helps others.

Comment: Yeah, I should have take a look at it, because I was missing the add method, which is present only in Eloquent\Collection. Edited.

Comment: @JofryHS If using `\Illuminate\Support\Collection`, you could use `$c->push(new Post);` instead of the add method.

Comment: I prefer to use the static method: `$c = \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::make();`. This ensures proper factory instantiation.

Comment: Make does exactly the same: `return new static($items);`

Comment: What If I need to wrap an array and then save it to DB. By wrapping it with Support\Collection I can't for example go foreach to save each element. How to convert it to Eloquent\Collection then?

Comment: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` is not the same as `\Illuminate\Support\Collection`. The first have specific methods for working with Models

Answer (score 15):

As of Laravel 5. I use the global function `collect()`

```
$collection = collect([]); // initialize an empty array [] inside to start empty collection
```

this syntax is very clean and you can also add offsets if you don't want the numeric index, like so:

```
$collection->offsetSet('foo', $foo_data); // similar to add function but with
$collection->offsetSet('bar', $bar_data); // an assigned index
```

Answer (score 11):

I've actually found that using `newCollection()` is more future proof....

Example:

```
$collection = (new Post)->newCollection();
```

That way, if you decide to create your own collection class for your model (like I have done several times) at a later stage, it's much easier to refactor your code, as you just override the `newCollection()` function in your model

Answer (score 7):

## Laravel >= 5.5

> This may not be related to the original question, but since it's one of the first link in google search, i find this helpful for those like me, who are looking for how to create empty collection.

If you want to manually create a ***new empty collection***, you can use the `collect` helper method like this:

```
$new_empty_collection = collect();
```

---

You can find this helper in `Illuminate\Support\helpers.php`

snippet:

```
if (! function_exists('collect')) {
    /**
     * Create a collection from the given value.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
     */
    function collect($value = null)
    {
        return new Collection($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: For the record, mention of the `collect()` helper was already edited into the accepted answer 2 years before you posted this answer.

Comment: is it possible to make an empty collection of type `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`?

Answer (score 5):

Just to add on to the accepted answer, you can also create an alias in `config/app.php`

```
'aliases' => array(

    ...
    'Collection'      => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::class,
```

Then you simply need to do

```
$c = new Collection;
```

Answer (score 5):

I am using this way :

```
$coll = new Collection();
    
$coll->name = 'name';
$coll->value = 'value';
$coll->description = 'description';
```

and using it as normal Collection

**dd($coll->name);**

Answer (score 4):

In Laravel 5 and Laravel 6 you can resolve the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` class out of the service container and then add models into it.

```
$eloquentCollection = resolve(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::class);
// or app(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::class). Whatever you prefer, app() and resolve() do the same thing.

$eloquentCollection->push(User::first());
```

For more information about understanding resolving objects out of the service container in laravel take a look here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container#resolving

Comment: This should 100% be the accepted answer. The other answers resolve to a support collection not an eloquent collection!

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to name the use namespace and instantiate it directly:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection as EloquentCollection;

# Usage
$this->latest_posts = new EloquentCollection();
```

Allowed me to merge two data subsets of eloquent collection results, this maintains the relationships - a regular collection (`collect()`) loses relationship and probably some more metadata.

```php
$limit = 5;
$this->latest_posts = new EloquentCollection();

$pinned_posts = PinnedPostReference::where('category', $category)->get();
if($pinned_posts->count() > 0) {
    foreach($pinned_posts as $ppost) {
        $this->latest_posts->push($ppost->post);
    }
}

# Another Eloquent result set ($regular_posts)
foreach($regular_posts as $regular_post) {
    $this->latest_posts->push($regular_post);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use the Injection Pattern and after `$this->collection->make([])` than `new Collection`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
...
// Inside of a clase.
...
public function __construct(Collection $collection){
    $this->collection = $collection;
}

public function getResults(){
...
$results = $this->collection->make([]);
...
}
```

Comment: If this remark is still valid, could you explain why?