# Eloquent Object - Method Chaining

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following Laravel Eloquent code, where there will be a lot of method chaining:

```
$foo = EloquentFoo::orderBy('xyz');

if(true)
{
    $foo->whereHas('eloquentModel',function($q){
        return $q->where('name','=','john');
    });
}
```

Given complex conditions, i need to instantiate the Eloquent Query Builder without using 'orderBy' or any other static methods.

I tried using the following, which fails miserably(don't know why):

```
$foo = new EloquentFoo;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23599775/358906 and the other answer below it.

Comment: Thanks, but i already tried; and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// get the query
$fooQuery = EloquentFoo::query();

// chain methods    
if (whatever) $fooQuery->whateverMethod();

// execute
$fooQuery->get();
```

Comment: Answer is spot on :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way around: I compare my primary key to something non-existing (not an OPTIMAL solution), would be interested to see the other solutions, though I thought this could help:

```
$foo = EloquentFoo::where('id','!=','0'); // id is the primary key and there is no row with value 0
// so basically above I am searching everything
// Perform Chaining Operation 
if(true)
{
    $foo->whereHas('eloquentModel',function($q){
        return $q->where('name','=','john');
    });
}
```

Note: You can use id as many times in the chain as you want and it would still work:

```
EloquentFoo::where('id','!=','0')->where('id','!=','0')->get()
```

Hopefully it helps ( I know it is not at all OPTIMAL).

Comment: Hehe, i added a `whereNull('deleted_at')` to go around the problem. Jarek gave the proper way to do it above :)

Comment: Yea, the answer looks more promising..thanks a lot for the question :)