# How to return empty list of records in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have some model `Task`.

If current user has permission then he can see all tasks

```
return Task::all();
```

If current user does not have this permission then he can see only empty list

```
return Task::where('id', 0)->get();
```

Design is so that user must always get some result, but my functions work with data returned from `Task::all()` so I can not return empty array or empty Eloquent collection.

What should I do?

Comment: Why you don't return an empty collection? Why it should be task eloquent collection?!

Comment: How you are going to check the user permission?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manually create a new empty Eloquent Collection in Laravel 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23599584/how-to-manually-create-a-new-empty-eloquent-collection-in-laravel-4)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want empty array, you don't want empty collection. Maybe you should change the design. Anyway, since you really want to pass an empty list of tasks, manually insert 1 o 2 tasks in the database as first tasks, so their IDs will always be 1 & 2. But leave everything else empty. Then you may always return those 2

```
return Task::whereIn('id', [1,2])->get();
```

My suggestion, is to actually fix the design to expect empty object, so you could do something like

```
return '';
```

Comment: This ties down your code to the database data. Your code will only work if those particular rows exist, and it's not obvious on the code why those IDs are hardcoded there.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to return a newly created Task object in an array if the JSON schema has to match exactly.  It would look like so:

```
$emptyTask = new Task();
return [$emptyTask]
```